# Python: Split data from csv file in format

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dataframe, split

I am trying to split `data['Title']` from CSV file  and separate:

- Brand Name
- Model Name
- Engine capacity *(like 2.2 or 500)*
- HorsePower *(number with KM)*
- EnginePower *(number with kW)*
- Model Year *(a single year or start_year-end_year)*

I did like this, but how can I add all **KM**, **KW**, **Year** and **engine capacity** in each single columns like this

Here is My Database Link In CSV File `https://www.kaggle.com/iamrraj/my-database` and here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("../input/Car_data_-_specs_-_Data.csv")
data1 = data.Title.str.split(" ",expand=True,)
data1.head()
data1.drop(data1.columns[11:18], axis=1, inplace=True)
data1.head(5)
```

And i am getting output like this

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   Abarth  124     Spider  1.4     T-Jet   170KM   125kW   2016-2019   None    None    None
1   Abarth  500     Cabrio  1.4     T-JET   135KM   99kW    2010    None    None    None
2   Abarth  500     Cabrio  1.4     T-JET   140KM   103kW   2011-2012   None    None    None
3   Abarth  500     Cabrio  Seria   1   1.4     T-Jet   16V     135KM   99kW    2014-2016
4   Abarth  500     Cabrio  Seria   1   1.4     T-Jet   16V     140KM   103kW   2012-2014
```

But i want data like this after split
SO how to do it please help me

```
HorsePower  EnginePower   Engine capacity   Model Year    Model Name   Brand Name
 100KM        20KM            2.2           2019-2020     Land Rover    LandRoverDefender
 80KM         40KM            500           2017-2018     Alfa Romeo    AlfaRomeoStelvio
```

Here Its After read csv file looks like

[image: Data looks Lik this aafter read]

Comment: Please show how `data` looks after `read_csv`

Comment: I added Image of data looks after read_csv@Fourier

Comment: Okay, I think u need to go for regex and match the groups. otherwise your results are not aligned.

Comment: Hello can you guide me how to do this. It will be very helpful @Fourier